# Python tkinter text widget for real-time logging

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI for my python app and I am struggling to get the Text Widget to behave like a stdout. More specifically, I want to the widget to display the information as soon as it is requested to do so and not at the end when everything is finished.

To demonstrate, consider this:

```
import sys
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import multiprocessing.queues as mpq
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import *


class StdoutQueue(mpq.Queue):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = mp.get_context()
        super(StdoutQueue, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs, ctx=ctx)

    def write(self,msg):
        self.put(msg)

    def flush(self):
        sys.__stdout__.flush()
        
        
def text_catcher(text_widget,queue):
    while True:
        text_widget.insert(END, queue.get())


def test_child(q):
    sys.stdout = q
    print('child running')


def test_parent(q):
    sys.stdout = q
    print('parent running')
    time.sleep(5.)
    mp.Process(target=test_child,args=(q,)).start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui_root = Tk()
    gui_txt = Text(gui_root)
    gui_txt.pack()
    q = StdoutQueue()
    gui_btn = Button(gui_root, text='Test', command=lambda: test_parent(q),)
    gui_btn.pack()

    monitor = Thread(target=text_catcher, args=(gui_txt, q))
    monitor.daemon = True
    monitor.start()

    gui_root.mainloop()
```

Hitting the `Test` button does not print `'parent running'` right away and `'child running'` 5 seconds later as desired, but rather, it waits 5 seconds and prints the two strings at once.

Is there any way to get the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand completely what is going on. `text_catcher` is being blocked when `test_parent` is called from the Tk thread. I would have assumed the monitor thread prevents this. Well...

One possible workaround could be to put `test_parent` in its own thread. This can be easily done with a small decorator:

```py
def run_in_thread(fun):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        thread = Thread(target=fun, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        thread.start()
        return thread

    return wrapper


@run_in_thread
def test_parent(q):
    sys.stdout = q
    print('parent running')
    time.sleep(5.)
    mp.Process(target=test_child, args=(q,)).start()
```

With `test_parent` wrapped like this, the text message appears immediatley.

Comment: I also thought the monitor thread will be enough but apparently it is not. To be more specific though, it is not the monitor that is threaded but more like the listener that keeps an eye on the queue and writes to the monitor. The monitor itself is refreshed only after the GIL is released. The extra thread for `test_parent` solves the issue by decoupling the refresh of the monitor with the process that is running.

Answer (score 0):

Just move `time.sleep(5.)` from test_parent into test_child:

```py
def test_child(q):
    sys.stdout = q
    time.sleep(5.)
    print('child running')


def test_parent(q):
    sys.stdout = q
    print('parent running')
    mp.Process(target=test_child, args=(q,)).start()
```

Even when I try it without `StdoutQueue` it works fine, here is the code:

```py
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
from tkinter import *


def test_child():
    time.sleep(5.)
    print('child running')


def test_parent():
    print('parent running')
    mp.Process(target=test_child, args=()).start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui_root = Tk()
    gui_txt = Text(gui_root)
    gui_txt.pack()
    gui_btn = Button(gui_root, text='Test', command=lambda: test_parent(), )
    gui_btn.pack()
    gui_root.mainloop()
```

Comment: on my system that does not make any difference

Comment: without it does work, but redirecting the stdout is not a requirement I can drop.